# Simple Alexa Skill Reading a txt File

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, alexa-skills-kit

I m sorry for my English. I need an alexa skill that reads the contents of a txt file. I think the best solution is to have the file on S3, but I can't find any guide on how to access the file and let alexa read it. 
I'm trying in various ways for now this is my code.

```
const ReadStoryIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
    && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'CaptureNameIntent';
},
async handle(handlerInput) {
let speakOut;
let option = {
    "Bucket" : "storytellingbucket",
    "Key" : "data/testo.txt"
}
await toGetS3(option).
then((response)=>{
    console.log(response),
    console.log(response.Body.toString()),
    speakOut = response
}).catch ((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    speakOut='there is an error'
})
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOut)
        .getResponse();
}
```

}

and the function

```
const toGetS3 = function (options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getObject(options, function (err, data) {
        //handle error
         if (err) {
        reject("Error", err);
        }
        //success
        if (data) {
        resolve(data.Body.toString())
   }
 })
```

})
 }

The code does not work. I have not been able to find a solution for days.

Comment: Any errors? What is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Alexa hosted skill then just put your story into your code structure create folder/file for that and read from it using fs.

Or you can create another js file which exports the story text and import it your main file/intent handler